# Number of samples and R^2

Tags: regression, linear-model

I have a linear regression model that gives me lower R^2 values as I increase the number of samples. The highest R^2 value I get is ~0.5, which makes me doubt that this is a problem related to overfitting. What would be an explanation for this observation?

Comment: Please describe your process of adding samples. It sounds like you got lucky with the small sample and then had the lack of fit revealed as you saw more data and get a better sense of the pattern.

Comment: I'm adding samples randomly according to the random number generation in Matlab.

Comment: So they’re completely random numbers, or do they follow some kind of pattern?

Comment: They are completely random numbers within a specified range.

Comment: Then $R^2$ should decrease; you’re introducing noise.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're adding is totally random, not coming from a certain mechanism that also generates your model, then this is not unexpected.

You are introducing noise to your model, which makes it performs worse.

---

If, however, in the other hand, the added samples are coming from the same mechanism that generates your model i.e. not made up, this will indicate something wrong.

1. The relationship between predictor and response is not that good, but you get lucky subset from the data that shows as if it is good.
2. There is a different relationship in the first sample and the later-added sample. This can happen if the two sample subsets are taken in different time or condition.